# Is there a good IDE for building GUI apps with Python

Tags: python, ironpython

I am a beginner programmer and have learned most of what I know thus far from using delphi for the past couple of months. A month or so back I decided to give python a try as I was told it may be easier to learn and I really like the language. I guess I just seem to pick things up easier using it.

The only problem is that I can't seem to find a good IDE for it that works in the way that Delphi does. I want to create desktop apps with nice GUIs so it would be nice to have something similar to Delphi/Visual studio to work with.

I have searched around and could find anything. Was wondering if anyone could lend a hand.

Also, from what I have gathered Ironpython seems to be the same as python coding wise. I don't mind my apps only being able to work on windows. Is [Python Tools](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) a good option. I mean is it basically like using visual studio but with python code instead?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boa Constructor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boa-constructor/?_test=beta) is a classic RAD IDE for GUI applications (wxpython, both linux and windows). People is still using it but seems that development stopped some years ago. [PythonCard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythoncard/?_test=beta) is another RAD IDE I used in the past but also unmaintained right now

Although they are not IDEs, some tools are very helpful for GUI design like:
- [wxglade](https://bitbucket.org/agriggio/wxglade) (wxpython, included as a pluging in Stani Python Editor, only python2.x)
- qtdesigner (qt-pyqt or pyside, included in [pyqt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro). [Spyder IDE](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/), build on pyqt, has a dedicated link to it. Works also for python 3.x)

Answer (score 1):

I use PyGTK to interact with GTK.

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-class-reference.html

http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/

But there is also QT, and WXpython, that are worthy.

Answer (score 1):

http://thekompany.com/products/blackadder/

Answer (score 0):

I always liked [BoaConstructor](http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/) which is a [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) GUI Builder.
Doesn't seems to be actively maintained any longer though...

wxpython is very active though...

Answer (score 0):

Python Tools is basically just like using VS but with Python.  It's got intellisense, debugging, profiling, etc...  When working w/ IronPython the .NET debugger is a little rough (you'll see internal implementation details) but you can still use the pure Python debugger which gives you a Pythonic view.

The intellisense engine is aware of the GUI designer so you'll get completions against the controls defined in XAML.  And you'll get auto-definition of handler methods when you do things like double click on buttons in the GUI designer or select to define an event handler in the properties pane.  Probably the biggest missing thing is that there's no support for user controls and there's also no designer support for WinForms.